# How do you create a configurable Ruby on Rails plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, ruby-on-rails-plugins

i am trying to create my first rails plugin, and i want it to be configurable, that is to say, i want to be able to set a variable in the environment.rb file or something.

UPDATE: i'm trying to do something like what's done here: http://soakedandsoaped.com/articles/read/exception-notifier-ruby-on-rails-plugin.  i have tried mimicking their code, but i can't get it working.

i have the plugin working with the value hard-coded, but everything i have tried so far for making it configurable hasn't worked.

Here's some of the code:

```
#vendor/plugin/markup/lib/markup_helper.rb
module MarkupHelper
    def stylesheet_cache_link_tag(*sources)
      cache = assests_cache_dir ? assests_cache_dir : ""
      options = sources.extract_options!.stringify_keys
      cached_name = options.delete("cached_name")
      stylesheet_link_tag(sources, :cache=> File.join(cache, cached_name))
    end

    def javascript_cache_include_tag(*sources)
      cache = assests_cache_dir ? assests_cache_dir : ""
      options = sources.extract_options!.stringify_keys
      cached_name = options.delete("cached_name")
      javascript_include_tag(sources, :cache=> File.join(cache, cached_name))
    end
end

#something like the following in config/environment.rb or probably config/environments/production.rb
MarkupConfig.assests_cache_dir = "cache"
```

i want assests_cache_dir to default to "cache" but be able to set in an environment config file.  i have googled a long time on this, and can't find anything discussing this.  How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

```
module MarkupHelper
  mattr_accessor :assets_cache_dir
  self.assets_cache_dir = "cache"

  def assets_cache_dir
    MarkupHelper.assets_cache_dir
  end
end
```

Then in environment.rb (or development.rb/test.rb/production.rb if you want different values for each environment):

```
MarkupHelper.assets_cache_dir = "my-value"
```

Comment: sweet, thx!  so what's the difference between attr_accessor and mattr_accessor (i'm a newbie to ruby obviously)?

Comment: mattr_accessor is rails-only, and defines accessors on an actual module.  attr_accessor defines accessors on instances of classes (not the classes themselves).

Comment: There is also `cattr_accessor` which defines accessors on the class itself.

Comment: so kind of like the difference between a static member and an instance member in C#? attr_accessor would be accessible only on an instantiated object (like an instance member in C#), and in rails, mattr_accessor and cattr_accessor would be accessible by just using the module name + dot or class name + dot, respectively (like a static member in C#)?

Comment: i guess i prematurely set this as the answer. i actually could not get the line for the config file to work. i am receiving "uninitialized constant MarkupHelper (NameError)" when i try to start the dev web server. here's all i have in my vendor/plugin/markup/init.rb: ActionView::Base.send :include, MarkupHelper

Comment: Seems like you are having an unrelated problem.  Where is MarkupHelper defined?  You should require the file it is defined in before referencing it.

Comment: it's a plugin, so i have it in vendor/plugin/markup/lib/markup_helper.rb.  so do i have to have a require 'vendor/plugin/markup/lib/markup_helper' in the environment config file (i.e. environment.rb)?

Answer (score 1):

Although the approach used by tomafro is quite easy to use, another approach is to use a database.yml-style configuration file that can be split according to environments:

> ```
> module MyPlugin
>   class Configuration
>     # == Constants ==========================================================
>
>     CONFIG_FILES = [
>       "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/myplugin.yml",
>       "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/myplugin.yaml"
>     ].freeze
>
>     DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION = {
>       :url => DEFAULT_HOSTNAME
>     }.freeze
>
>     # == Class Methods ======================================================
>
>     # :nodoc:
>     def self.config_file_found
>       CONFIG_FILES.find do |path|
>         File.exist?(path)
>       end
>     end
>
>     # Returns the default path to the configuration file
>     def self.default_path
>       config_file_found or CONFIG_FILES.first
>     end
>
>     # == Instance Methods ===================================================
>
>     # Creates a new MyPlugin::Configuration instance by reading from the
>     # configuration file.
>     # +env+ The Rails environment to load
>     def initialize(env)
>       config_file = self.class.config_file_found
>
>       @env_config = DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION
>
>       if (@config = (config_file and YAML.load(File.open(config_file))))
>         [ @config['defaults'], @config[env] ].each do |options|
>           if (options)
>             @env_config = @env_config.merge(options.symbolize_keys)
>           end
>         end
>       end
>     end
>
>     # Will return +true+ if a configuration file was found and loaded, or
>     # +false+ otherwise.
>     def exists?
>       @env_config != DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION
>     end
>
>     # Returns a particular configuration option.
>     def [](key)
>       @env_config[key.to_sym]
>     end
>   end
>
>   def self.config
>     @config ||= Configuration.new(Rails.env)
>   end
> end
> ```

You would use this as:

> ```
> settting = MyPlugin.config[:param_name]
> ```

You can also write utility methods to fetch particular values, or use OpenStruct instead of a configuration Hash. This is posted merely as an example of another design pattern.